# Accepted notation for sparsity/density of a network

Tags: neural-networks, notation, networks

Is there an accepted notation in the study of network structure for the measure of network sparsity and/or density?

For example, I see $\rho$ is typically used for spectral radius, $\alpha$ for leak rate of neuron units, $\beta$ for regularization coefficients, and so forth. Is there a go-to symbol for network sparsity?

Comment: When do you say 'sparsity', do you mean that weight matrix in neural network are 'sparse' (and the same for 'dense')?

Comment: I'm dealing specifically with reservoir computing and recurrent networks where the units are not fully connected like traditional feed-forward networks. I suppose I should edit my answer to just be network study generally, since it's probably not as common a measure in neural networks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Network science: Network properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_science#Network_properties) at Wikipedia:

- **Network density** (i.e. ratio of edges to maximal possible number of edges, given the number of nodes)
- **Average degree** (i.e twice the average number of edges per node)

See also: [Densely connected networks - network-science.org](http://www.network-science.org/highly-connected-society-dense-social-complex-networks.html) and [dense graph - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph).

If you can scale your network, you can look at the behavior $E = a N^b$, searching for $a$ and $b$. For $b=2$ a network would be dense, for $b=1$ - sparse, and in between - opinions/definitions can vary.